# ViewDidLoad and ViewDidUnload always cause

Tags: ios, ios5

Please tell me how or what to write so that always causes ViewDidLoad ViewDidUnload?

IOS5 and Storyboard.

Read a similar topic, but did not understand what it takes to do it.

thanks

Comment: Hey guys, please don't close this question yet. Give him some time to edit it.

Comment: @JDev, you need to be more clear on what help you need from us.

Comment: SO will not provide you code, you need to be able to look into this yourself at a certain level

Answer (score 2):

viewDidLoad will be called whenever a view controller's view object is loaded (either from a nib, storyboard or manually using loadView).

viewDidUnload is not guaranteed to be called, and in fact in iOS6 and onwards, it doesn't even exist. It is only called when a view controller's view is not on the screen, and the system is under memory pressure. You shouldn't have any code in there that you *need* to call. That should be in dealloc, or viewDidDisappear, depending on what the code does.

Comment: dealloc() also not called.!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to call a function before loading the new View and after his disappearance and transfer to another. Not any more.